# Can RLMResults be typecasted to NSArray?

Tags: realm

We are trying to integrate Realm into our ios app in an iterative manner. Currently we have a lot of variables of the type NSArray which will ultimately have to be replaced by RLMResults.
But for now I was wondering if the data from Realm db could be loaded into those variables. 
Here is an example of one such function :

```
func preloadData() {
    if( realmEnabled )
    {
        if( self.currentLeftSideBarState == GLOBAL_CUSTOMER_STATE ) {
            self.allRelations = Relationship.allObjectsInRealm(relationshipRealm)
        } else if( self.currentLeftSideBarState == SINGLE_CUSTOMER_STATE ) {
            let rel = Relationship( customers: currentCustomerSelected! )
            if rel.realm != nil {
                if let rooms = rel.linkingObjectsOfClass( RoomObj.className(), forProperty: "relationship" ) {
                    self.allRoomsforRelationship = rooms
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `allRelations` is an `RLMResults` object while `allRoomsForRelationship` is an `NSArray`. This leads to several inconsistencies. 
It would be convenient to typecast `RLMResults` to `NSArray`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand exactly what your question is

Comment: In a word, No. `RLMResults` is not derived from `NSArray`, so the compiler will not let you cast it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Since `RLMResults` doesn't inherit from `NSArray`, casting to an `NSArray` is dangerous -- you'd lose all type safety. What you may want to look into is whether changing those declarations to `id<NSFastEnumerable>` makes sense for your application, or else maybe declaring a protocol which has the methods common to both `NSArray` and `RLMResults`.